# Ubuntu 16.04 guest on Virtualbox not getting IP from host

Tags: networking, dhcp, virtualbox-networking

I have set up various VMs with Ubuntu 16.04 guests and Windows 10 hosts in different physical locations, nevertheless with a stable internet connection. Expecting the hosts to provide an IP address through Virtualbox to all these Virtual OSs, configured with a NAT network adapter (default settings), have a purpose to connect to a server.

For some reason this works perfectly okay for some Virtual OSs and I hope to be guided through a debug to solve this situation.

`ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a3:5b:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::6467:c72f:f210:ad4e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:93:64:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`:
*NOTE: the following configuration is the same for all the OSs, which makes me think 'network manager' has nothing to do with the IP assigning procedure since most guests get their IPs, not sure though.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I am currently stuck rebooting the guests that fail to get their IPs at their first try to get around the connection problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Intel adapter, here's my quick workaround:

In the host environment (e.g Windows -> Device Manager) turn the Intel adapter off and then turn it on again. After 5...10 seconds check the guest again,

```
ifconfig -a
```

...it should get the IP without restarting the host system.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/network/interfaces` you're saying to get an IP via DHCP for interface `eth0` yet you don't have that interface. You have interface `enp0s3` and `enp0s8`. So if you're using `enp0s3` just change:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Well see, if that is really the problem, how is it possible for the all the other VMs to get an IP for they have the same interface configuration using "eth0" and also have interfaces enp0s3 and enp0s8. I will most definitely give a try though, thanks for your reply!

Comment: That's where network manager comes in. Because things were too easy they introduced this network manager, so interfaces listed with auto in /etc/network/interfaces are managed by ifup/ifdown/ifconfig if interface is not listed there it's managed by network manager. Click on the GUI in your taskbar click on edit connections (interfaces with auto will be listed as "device not managed") select interface you want to manage/edit/IPv4 settings tab/Set Methode to Automatic (DHCP)

Comment: Also to **temporary** check that DHCP server is reachable on interface enp0s3 `sudo dhclien -v -r enp0s3` and then `sudo dhclien -v enp0s3`

Comment: OkOk so let me see if I understand this correctly. Because the interface "enp0s3" was not listed in /etc/network/interfaces it was managed by the network manager, which didn't do anything because there was no ethernet connection configuration profile for "enp0s3", is that right?

Comment: To follow up on checking whether the DHCP server is reachable, the answer is no. It gets stuck on broadcasting (DHCPDISCOVER message).If I reboot the VM, no changes made in either the /etc/network/interfaces  configuration or the network manager configuration, it does get a respond using the same port as before and does get an IP assign.

Comment: **Because the interface "enp0s3" was not listed in /etc/network/interfaces it was managed by the network manager** `YES correct`  **which didn't do anything because there was no ethernet connection configuration** `NO by default Network Manager would be set up interface for DHCP `

Comment: So there's your problem. Guest is asking for an IP via DHCP and (since it's NATed) for some reason VMware on host doesn't answer. Look at firewall on Windows? But very odd that it gets it after a reboot?

Comment: Yea very odd that after a reboot the guest does get an IP. I will try 3 different scenarios in different hosts and see what happens. In one I will turn off Windows Firewall completely, on another host I will only edit /etc/network/interfaces configuration, and on a third host I will combine the previously taken steps.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing worked. Same exact problem. I should mention that this issue wouldn't happen before when I was working with Ubuntu 14, not till I upgraded the Ubuntu guest to 16 was when I started experiencing this problem. To be clear, if I were to boot up at host's startup these  2 versions of Ubuntu, which I have, Ubuntu 14.04 would get an IP assigned by VirtualBox with no problem.

Comment: **If I reboot the VM, no changes made in either the /etc/network/interfaces configuration or the network manager configuration, it does get a respond using the same port as before and does get an IP assign.** can you explain this? It doesn't work but then it does work? And why do you have two network adapters? enp0s3 and enp0s8? Are both of them set up for NAT?

Comment: What I meant was that rebooting the guest seems to make the DHCP  request work whether I have declared enp0s3 or not.  To be honest, I do not know why am I getting that enp0s8 interface. I have a local network adapter, and the NAT adapter enabled.

Comment: Go to your vbox settings -> Network, and go through all four Adapters and make sure only the first one has a check in "Enable Network Adapter" and that Adapter Type is your correct network card and Attached To is set to NAT

Comment: Well, tried different things over the weekend and switching from the Intel adapter to the AMD adapter did the trick. I am unable to come to a conclusion, thought that actually the switch to a new MAC address of the adapter was the answer, but unfortunately no. I currently have a number of hosts working with the Intel adapter and a group of other hosts working with the AMD adapter. Thinking maybe the Ubuntu guests are missing packages to be able to work with the Intel adapter?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions by the way. I would vote your answer if I could.

Answer (score 0):

This happens rarely with the new Vbox updates; it works just fine if I downgrade it back to previous version.

The recent update did it again (v6.0.8) because of the Windows 10 updates this time (and always will).

this simple ifdown and up commands works instantly for me.

```
ifconfig enp0s3 down
sleep 7
ifconfig enp0s3 up
```

sometimes, it takes more around 10 seconds until the host (Windows 10) detects the new IP from the NIC.

The best solution is to downgrade and wait until the newer version releases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a Ubuntu 16.04 issue itself.

I have been using 16.04 OS (Host) on a MS Surface Go and sometimes when I power on the device the Ubuntu 16 OS does not get an IP (DHCP).

I have to physically disconnect and connect the USB-C to LAN Ethernet adapter and then it gets an IP. That point I thought it was a Surface Go issue or LAN adapter issue.

But when the same happened recently on a Ubuntu 16.04 Guest VM, it got me quite surprised.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is exactly what [Seandex suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/1157573/618353), just using the `ip` command, as follows:

```
sudo ip link enp0s3 down
sudo ip link enp0s3 up
sudo ip link enp0s8 down
sudo ip link enp0s8 up
```

I'm using `ip` now that `ifconfig` is absent by default and not installed anymore with the `net-tools` package.